# Set DataSource for MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have started to learn android for 3 months and I have some problems with MediaPlayer.setDataSource

I want to get path of mp3 file in my raw directory, which is used for Media Player.

I have tried many ways but the app's still not working, even though the program doesn't crash or show problems. I have tried many solutions from other posts but it's still not working.
Here is my code:

```
String path = "android.resource://com.example.acer.appdemo/raw/emer2";
bleeding1.setDataSource(path);
bleeding1.prepareAsync();
bleeding1.start();

textView.setText(getString(R.string.Firstaid2));
count = 2;
```

The reason why I choose this, because I want to make a program that change audio every time I swipe left or right. So I want the program setDataSource again each time I swipe left or right, and the code above is one of my cases (The audio doesn't start everytimes I put a new path).

Answer (score 1):

You have to reset the MediaPlayer (call bleeding1.reset()) before you can set a new data source.
See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html for a helpful lifecyle diagram.

Comment: I also add bleeding1.reset() and bleeding1.stop() but it doesn't work, I think the problem is my path, but I don't know how to check the app can access the file in raw directory. Is there any way to test or check this ?

Comment: Instead of using a path, you could use MediaPlayer.create(Context, int) to instantiate your MediaPlayer. This method takes your context and the resource id, in your case R.raw.emer2. That works reliably and you don't even have to call prepare() / prepareAsync(). The downside is that you would have to create a new instance of your MediaPlayer everytime you want to change the data source.